# Cypher pattern for getting self related nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given that I'm very new to Neo4j. I have a schema which looks like the below image:
[image]

Here `Has` nodes are different for example `Passport, Merchant, Driving License, etc.` and also these nodes are **describing the customer node (looking for future scope of filtering customers based on these nodes)**.

`SIMILAR` is a self-relation meaning there exists a customer with `ID:1` is related to another customer with `ID:2` with a score of `2800`.

I have the following questions:

1. Is this a good schema given the condition of the future scope I mentioned above, or getting all the properties in a single customer node is viable? (Different nodes may have array of items as well, for example: `()-[:HAS]->(Phone)` having `{active: "+91-1231241", historic_phone_numbers: ["+91-121213", "+91-1231421"]}`)
2. I want to get the customer along with describing nodes in relation to other customers. For that, I tried the below query (w/o number of relation more than 1):

```
// With number_of_relation > 1
MATCH (searched:Customer)-[r:SIMILAR]->(matched:Customer)
WHERE r.score > 2700
WITH searched, COLLECT(matched.customer_id) AS MatchedList, count(r) as cnt
WHERE cnt > 1
UNWIND MatchedList AS matchedCustomer
MATCH (person:Customer {customer_id: matchedCustomer})-[:HAS|:LIVES_IN|:IS_EMPLOYED_BY]->(related)
RETURN searched, person, related
```

Result what I got is below, notice one customer node not having its describing nodes:

[image]

```
// without number_of_relation > 1
// second attempt - for a sample customer_id
MATCH (matched)<-[r:SIMILAR]-(c)-[:HAS|:LIVES_IN|:IS_EMPLOYED_BY]->(b)
WHERE size(keys(b)) > 0
AND c.customer_id = "1b093559-a39b-4f95-889b-a215cac698dc"
AND r.score > 2700
RETURN b AS props, c AS src_cust, r AS relation,  matched
```

Result I got are below, notice related nodes are not having their describing nodes:

[image]

3. If I had two describing nodes with some property (some may have a list) upon which I wanted to query and build the expected graph specified in point 2 above, how can I do that?
4. I want the database to find a similar customer given the describing nodes. Example: A `customer {name: "Dave"}` has `phone {active_number: "+91-12345"}` is *similar* to `customer {name: "Mike"}` has `phone {active_number: "+91-12345"}`. How can get started with this?

If something is unclear, please ask. I can explain with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]

1. Yes, the schema seems fine, except that you should not use the same `HAS` relationship type between different node label pairs.
2. The main problem with your first query is that its top `MATCH` clause uses a *directional* relationship pattern, `()-->()`, which does not allow all `Customer` nodes to have a chance to be the `searched` node (because some nodes may only be at the *tail end* of `SIMILAR` relationships). This tweaked query should work better:

   ```
   MATCH (searched:Customer)-[r:SIMILAR]-(matched:Customer)
   WHERE r.score > 2700
   WITH searched, COLLECT(matched) AS matchedList
   WHERE SIZE(matchedList) > 1
   UNWIND matchedList AS person
   MATCH (person)-[:HAS|LIVES_IN|IS_EMPLOYED_BY]->(pDesc)
   WITH searched, person, COLLECT(pDesc) AS personDescribers
   MATCH (searched)-[:HAS|LIVES_IN|IS_EMPLOYED_BY]->(sDesc)
   RETURN searched, person, personDescribers, COLLECT(sDesc) AS searchedDescribers
   ```
3. *It's not clear what you want are trying to do.*
4. To get all `Customer`s who have the same phone number:

   ```
   MATCH (c:Customer)-[:HAS_PHONE]-(p:Phone)
   WHERE p.activeNumber = '+91-12345'
   WITH p.activeNumber AS phoneNumber, COLLECT(c) AS customers
   WHERE SIZE(customers) > 1
   RETURN phoneNumber, customers
   ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out for `HAS`. Also, for the `-->` in the second point. After working on it for a long time I figured out the part where I was not able to get `describing nodes` for all the `customer nodes`. About the 3rd point, it was to do with filtering that anyways is covered. **4th point, if for example, I was not providing the p.activeNumber explicitly then how is it possible to get customers with matching phone number nodes?**

Comment: Just omit the first `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @cybersame while I was doing my analysis on the resulting data. There lies a relationship redundancy i.e. `A --> B` also `B --> A` for a single record I'm getting 2. which is kinda expected by removing the `-->` but how can I achieve the same without duplicate records.

Comment: Are you talking about my first query? Can you give an example of the "duplication"?

Comment: It was a naive mistake by me. Thanks, @cybersam Don't mind if I tag you in any proceeding question related to cypher here onwards.

Comment: In the 2nd point of your answer, you didn't mention about getting the describing nodes for the searched customer! 
I tried this `MATCH (person)-[:HAS|LIVES_IN|IS_EMPLOYED_BY]->(related), (searched)-[:HAS|LIVES_IN|IS_EMPLOYED_BY]->(searchedRelated) `. But this gives me the warning of cartesian product. How do I overcome this?

Comment: Solved it but unsure if it good or not but query is: `MATCH (searched:Customer)-[r:SIMILAR]-(matched:Customer)
MATCH (searched)-[:HAS_DRIVER_LICENSE|:HAS_PASSPORT|:HAS_PHONE]->(search_related)
WHERE r.score > 2700
WITH searched, COLLECT(matched) AS matchedList, search_related
WHERE SIZE(matchedList) > 1
UNWIND matchedList AS person
MATCH 
    (person)-[:HAS_DRIVER_LICENSE|:HAS_PASSPORT|:HAS_PHONE]->(related)
RETURN searched, person, related, search_related`